# Angular 8 - How can validate input files in ngfor with formBuilder

Tags: angular, forms, typescript, validation, angular8

I need your help because can't make it.

I making a form in Angular 8 using `formBuilder` for validate null fields and some validation.

I have 2 dropdowns with validations and this is working fine, but in my form I have also a `*ngFor`  that runs through a list of objects from an api. Each of these objects have name of file requested, description of file requested . These objects are data for the different input files that will appear according to the number of records that have that list.

In this case I have 3 records, in the front-end appear 3 input files like file 1, file 2, file 3 how in
the next image.

[Imagen 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fKXCr.png)

And this is my html code.

```
 <div class="col-md-6" *ngFor="let rpt of ReporteListData; let i = index"> 
     <div class="form-group">
         <label>{{rpt.nombre}} <small  class="text-muted">({{rpt.tipo}})</small><strong class="required-field">*</strong></label>
         <span class="info-tooltip"><i class="md-info" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="{{rpt.descripcion}}"></i></span>
         <div class="form-group">                                                                                                                       
             <input type="file" >           
         </div>
     </div>
 </div>
```

In my component.ts I have `formBuilder` validation for others component of the form but I don't know how call inputs files inside `ngFor` in my `formBuilder` for validate in each of the input file paths.

This is my code in component.ts

```
  this.CumplimientoForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      cbxtema: ['', Validators.required],
      cbxperiodo: ['', Validators.required],
      checkboxconfirm: [false, Validators.requiredTrue],

      //here code like inputsfiles[i] or array: validations. ??? 

   });
```

I tried with `FormArray` or something like this but doesn't work,

thank you very much for your help,

Greetings.